# What is the proper order of SQLAlchemy transactions vs sessions?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm a bit confused by SQLAlchemy's terminology around transactions--there appears to be both DB-level transactions and Session-level transactions.

My current understanding: `Sessions(session-level transactions(db-level transactions()))`

I'm using transactions together with scoped sessions to as part of a test fixture. I initiate a transaction, create the data and see if the test passes, then rollback the transaction before the next test.

Here is my code:

```
connection = db.engine.connect()
transaction = connection.begin()
options = dict(bind=connection, binds={})
db.session = db.create_scoped_session(options=options)
yield db.session
transaction.rollback()
connection.close()
db.session.remove()
```

As you can see, currently I create a scoped session after creating the transaction, but then rollback the transaction before removing the session.

Questions:

1. Is the transaction I'm creating here a session-level or db-level transaction?
2. Should I swap these so the transaction is created inside the scoped session?
3. Or go fully the other way and remove the session before rolling back the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically view the session as a super-transaction, within a session you can open and close multiple transactions (only one at a time though) to read and write data.

1. The `create_scoped_session` is actually a flask-sqlalchemy extension, but in the background it uses the standard SQLAlchemy session creation code. So you are using both here.
2. You should ignore the transactions, SQLAlchemy handles these for you. The advantage of an abstraction layer like SQLAlchemy is that it even works (up to a certain level) on databases without transaction support.
3. Just let flask-sqlalchemy handle it for you completely, here's an example with committing:

   ```
   your_object = YourObject(...)
   db.session.add(your_object)
   db.session.commit()
   ```

   And an example rolling back:

   ```
   your_object = YourObject(...)
   db.session.add(your_object)
   db.session.rollback()
   ```

   It all depends how you use it though, your code suggests this is within a `flask` session where this would work. Outside you would need a different solution

Comment: Thanks for the answer--your mention of scoped sessions gave me the clues for better understanding the SQLA session. The sample code I was working with was actually an example of the [SQLalchemy pattern of joining an external transaction](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites). For this pattern, it seems important to explicitly manage the session/transaction interaction. This [issue on Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/243) links to a blog post with more info.